# Add civirule for Chasse

Tags: civirules

I'm trying to configure Chasse for some automated email campaigns for new supporters.
I understand I need to add a new CiviRule action (we installed Chasse after CiviRule but it has added a new rule as this documentation has said it would)
https://docs.civicrm.org/chasse/en/latest/starting/#manually-installing-the-civirules-action
Can anyone talk me through manually adding the required rule? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Support - Developer - Api Explorer v3.
Select Entity CiviRuleAction, Action create.
Add in the top three parameters as indicated on the page you've linked to (you don't need is_active, that'll be set by default).
Click Execute.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the help. If this has worked as it should would it appear under the list of rules in CiviRule? Because it hasn't :D

Comment: Sorry, ignore that - I've understood what it has happened. Its added the action to be able to add the rule, not the rule itself. Thanks